# What is correct, Procedural Oriented Programming or Procedural Programming?

Tags: procedural-programming

Can someone please tell me whether calling `Procedural Programming` as `Procedural Oriented Programming` is correct or not?

Comment: the term is "procedural programming", not "procedural oriented programming"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say 'procedural programming' is correct and more common. However, since it's often contrasted with object-oriented programming, 'procedural-oriented programming' has become more common.

I'd say it's technically wrong though. First off, they're not opposed, you can have an object-oriented procedural language and do both. Secondly, a procedural language is procedural, not just 'procedure-oriented'. Similarly, some people call specific languages that are more object-oriented than others by design 'object-based'.

Another cause for confusion may be protocol-oriented programming (pop), which is an acronym that is sometimes (incorrectly) associated with procedural programming.

Wikipedia provides a good overview of the common programming paradigms and their correct names https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_paradigms

Answer (score 0):

From what I have studied, procedural programming is correct . This approach focuses more on the process.

Comment: Also, this is not applicable in case of Python, since we have object-oriented programming in Python